# Drupal site in Google search results

Tags: drupal-7, seo

I have setup a personal Drupal v.7 freelancer site which doesn't display in Google search results when searching based on home page title or other main keywords. It's home page title is "Professional X-Cart services".

The site is http://www.craftforweb.com and if you for example, do a Google search, using the text "X-Cart services" or "X-Cart" in Google, it won't be displayed even in the first 20 result pages. On the other hand, in Yahoo, it gets displayed on the first page and in Bing, it gets displayed in the 2nd search result page.

The site is displayed on Google search results only if you use it's domain name as search string (and maybe some other string, which I am not aware currently).

The site has been on for almost 5 months now.
I have used metatags for the site pages, also have installed "Pathauto", "Page Title" modules and have enabled clean URL's.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

For better on-site optimisation, you can install the [SEO Checklist](https://drupal.org/project/seo_checklist) module and implement best practice. Another advice not related with programing is to get backlink from your customer web site.